# How can I make friendly urls for my site?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So far I include everything in index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

There are also pages where I use $_GET like this:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ".intval($_GET['id'])
```

If I want to view a news I type `news?id=1`
instead of `?page=news&id=1` but I want to be able to use `news/1`.

Will I have to add a rewrite rule for every page where I use GET? Or is there a better way?

I hope I don't have to do this for all my pages.

Comment: to clarify you want your *id* to equal "news/1" not "1"?

Comment: I think he means he wants the end of his url too look like stuff.com/news/1 in the browser.

Comment: using [^/]* (anything but a slash) instead of .* (anything) and then using a /? (perhaps a slash) fixed it so it doesn't require a random slash at the end anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this single rule should allow both with and without ids (and also makes the slashes optional):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*)/?)?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

if you don't want to allow / and //, change the `*`'s to `+`'s

Comment: + matches 1 or more, ? matches 0 or 1. Shouldn't it be a '?'?

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Should allow your pages to be entered as `www.example.com/page/id`

Most of your pages will internally look like `www.example.com/index.php?page=text&id=` but that shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: Ok, I change a few things around, it shouldn't require a slash at the end anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just use news/1, which will already work with your current rewrite rules and puts that value into the page parameter. Then create a generic URL dispatcher in your index.php that parses the value of the page parameter into component pieces, and decides what to do based on those pieces.

For example, a really simple generic dispatcher would just split the page parameter on "/", and then call a handler based on the value of the first item returned from the split (e.g. "news"), passing the rest of the pieces (e.g. "1") as arguments to the handler.

EDIT: Grammar, and a [link to tutorials on URL dispatching in PHP](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/category/url-routing/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Or you could parse the requested path with PHP:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [QSA,L]


// remove the query string from the request URI
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = preg_replace('/\?.*/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// removes leading and trailing slashes and explodes the path
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
var_dump($segments);
```